# choco publish x86 and x64 packages

Tags: chocolatey

I must be missing something. I'd like to push two versions of my package - x86 and x64. How is this done? I failed to find any documentation about it, but it appears to be possible based on this issue: https://github.com/chocolatey/ChocolateyGUI/issues/262

So how do I publish two flavors of the same package?

Comment: Do you *need* two distinct versions of your package? Or is it okay if the package handles both the 32 and 64 bit case depending on platform?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a pressing need for two versions of the same package, you don't need two of them. Chocolatey's helper functions support 32 and 64 bit files from within the same `chocolateyInstall.ps1` script.

See [`Install-ChocolateyPackage`](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/create/functions/install-chocolateypackage) for details (other helpers have 32 and 64 bit differentiators as well) but for the parameters which have a `64` counterpart (e.g. `-File` and -`File64`), `-File` should be the 32 bit value and `-File64` should be the 64 bit value. The others work much in the same way. Example:

```
$installPkgArgs = @{
  File = 'https://server.domain.tld/installer32.msi'
  File64 = 'https://server.domain.tld/installer64.msi
  Checksum = '32bitinstallerchecksum'
  Checksum64 = '64bitinstallerchecksum'

  # Other args like SilentArgs, etc.
}

Install-ChocolateyPackage @installPkgArgs
```

On the client side, if forcing the 32-bit or 64-bit version is desired (e.g. when installing the 32-bit version on 64-bit system), `choco install --forceX86 pkg` will achieve what you want. It's very unlikely (though not impossible) that you have a use case where using a single package won't work for your needs.